# Build SOAP Java client with authentication

Tags: java, authentication, soap

I need to build a SOAP Java client with user and password.
I'm using jax-ws but I don't know how to valid authentication.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:7777/path/method.asmx?wsdl");

    QName qname = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "Service1Soap");

    Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

    Service1Soap service1 = service.getPort(Service1Soap.class);

    System.out.println(service1.method("testParam"));
```

Can somebody help me!

Comment: I don't know where I can set value for username and password.

Comment: What kind of authentication is the backend using.  I'm hoping basic auth (the kind that if you point your web browser at, you get a generic popup that prompts user for username/password); I had to deal with a more esoteric microsoft-based auth which is doable but which required a different process

Comment: Oh, thank you Foon. I have found the reason I did not pass the authentication of that webservice. It requires the IP address of the client in its own whitelist. Anyway, thank you for looking at my problem! Wish you stay healthy!